# Constant for functionColumnReturn of DatabaseMetaData#getFunctionColumns?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-metadata

According to [`DatabaseMetaData#getFunctionColumns`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getFunctionColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), the result column of `COLUMN_TYPE` may be one of

- [`functionColumnUnknown` (`0`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#functionColumnUnknown)
- [`funtionColumnIn` (`1`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#functionColumnIn)
- [`functionColumnInOut` (`2`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#functionColumnInOut)
- [`functionColumnOut` (`3`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#functionColumnOut)
- `functionColumnReturn`
- [`functionColumnResult` (`5`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#functionColumnResult)

Where is the constant for `functionColumnReturn`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there's a typo (and it's been that way since its inception in `1.6`).

It's not `functionColumnReturn`, it's just [functionReturn (4)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#functionReturn).

Comment: Your answer, FYI, has been logged, my friend. https://github.com/jinahya/database-metadata-bind/blob/27729f1b55e8055ed9be8ae71743277b00649b70/src/main/java/com/github/jinahya/database/metadata/bind/FunctionColumn.java#L76